# How can I create my own BaseEntity using PanacheEntityBase?

Tags: jpa, quarkus-panache

I am using Panache ORM (with Postgresql) and I would like to add a column to every entity I have.

I have this:

```
@Entity
public class MyTable extends PanacheEntityBase {
    // My columns
}
```

I would like this:

```
@Entity
public class MyBaseEntity extends PanacheEntityBase {
    public String someId;
}

@Entity
public class MyTable extends MyBaseEntity {
    // My columns
}
```

Now this does not work since Panache is now looking for the "base_entity" Table, which does not exist.

Can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `MyBaseEntity` has not table you have to replace `@Entity` with `@MappedSuperclass`

```
@MappedSupperclass
public class MyBaseEntity extends PanacheEntityBase {
    public String someId;
}
```

`MappedSuperclass` tells JPA to use the attributes of this class in the subclasses.

Please also checkout the docs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-mapped-superclass

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I was looking for a solution within panache that I forgot about the out-of-the-box JPA annotations. Thanks.